# Express the statement “ for each region belonging to each country in N" mathematically

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set of countries called N and subsets of regions belonging to each of those countries. I would like to ask for some help with notation.

I would like to express mathematically, "for each region belonging to each country in N". I wrote

> ∀r∈R ∧ ∀R∈N

where r is a region in a country R belonging to a set of countries N. I'm pretty sure this is either not correct or that there is a better way to express it, so I would like to ask for your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be
$$\forall R\in N\,\forall r\in R\ldots$$
The difference is that you should not use the conjunction between the quantifiers and you should write them in such order that the variables are defined before you use them (you used $R$ before defining it). The order of the quantifiers becomes even more important when you mix $\exists$ and $\forall$ in one sentence.

Usually, when we write a *mathematical sentence*, we should give a statement after the quantifiers, for example *there is at least one person living in each region of each country* would be
$$\forall R\in N\, \forall r\in R\ \textrm{someone is living in r},$$
or if you let $\phi(r)$ be the number of people living in region $r$, then you could write
$$\forall R\in N\, \forall r\in R\ \  \phi(r)>0.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your in-depth explanation!